# Swift IOS - UILabel skip last of LargeText if firstView

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyPostCell", for: indexPath) as! MyPostCell
     let postInfo = myPost[indexPath.row]
     cell.content.text = postInfo["Content"] as! String
     return cell
     }

class MyPostCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var content: UILabel!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()


    }
}
```

my Table if first view skip largeText

[image: FirstView]

but 
It scrolls down once and then looks right when it scrolls up

[image: after scroll]

how to view same it scrolled when first view

If the text is small, it looks the same

Text appears different if it is more than a certain size

Comment: Can you show the code of your `PostCell `

Comment: @QuocNguyen PostCell have UILabel just.

Comment: Can you explain clearly what should happening in the beginning? Should it skip the first label if it's too big? If so then what is too big? Also why only the first cell?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri 
If you look at last of my first  picture 
At the end, ... is only for the first visible cell. Scroll down once and come up as second picture